# Retrieve mongodb documents with int as _id

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine, objectid

I imported some wikipedia documents into mongodb with int type "_id" field (they are the pageids for wikipedia page):

```
> db.wiki_page_id.find()
{ "_id" : 10, "page_title" : "AccessibleComputing" }
{ "_id" : 12, "page_title" : "Anarchism" }
```

I am using Mongo engine together with Django, and I am having trouble retrieving the documents I imported. When I use the following code:

```
page_id_doc = WikiPageId.objects(id=10)[0]
```

it reports this error:

> u'10' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input of type 'str' or a 24-character hex string

When I use the `bson.objectid.ObjectId` class as this:

```
page_id_doc = WikiPageId.objects(id=ObjectId(10))[0]
```

It reports the following error:

> id must be an instance of (str, unicode, ObjectId), not

Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MongoEngine, you can define a field in your document as the "primary key" ( "_id" field by using `primary_key` in the [keyword arguments](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#fields) to the field:

```
class MyClass(Document):
    id = IntField(primary_key=True)
```

But of course you need to make sure that "type" is used everywhere in your collection otherwise the type checking will fail for any "_id" that is not an `int()`.